# What is missing to make my cascading DropDownList work

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Very easy case displayed here: http://jsbin.com/ahoYoPi/3/edit

I need to specify that the child's inner field to filter (eq) against the parent's value field is "category_id"... Of course, Kendo's documentation doesn't say anything about how to do that... Or is it something so super obvious it doesn't deserve to be explained ?

```
    var categoriesList = new Array (
    {"id":"1","categoryName":"Fruits"},
    {"id":"2","categoryName":"Vegetables"} );

var productsList = new Array(
    {"id":"1","categorie_id":"1","productName":"Apples"},
    {"id":"2","categorie_id":"1","productName":"Oranges"},
    {"id":"3","categorie_id":"2","productName":"Carottes"},
    {"id":"4","categorie_id":"2","productName":"Patatoes"});

$("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "categoryName",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: categoriesList,
    optionLabel: "----------------" ,
    change: function() {
        $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList").value(0);
    }
});
$("#products").kendoDropDownList({
    cascadeFrom: "categories",
    dataTextField: "productName",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: productsList,
    optionLabel: "----------------" ,
});
```

Comment: Can you change in `categoriesList` the `id` to `categorie_id`? If so, you can do it and then in the first `kendoDropDownList` say that `dataValueField` is `categorie_id` (see it [here](http://jsbin.com/OLUnACa/3/edit))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation about cascading is available here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/combobox/cascading

Here is how filtering works:

> If the parent has a value, then the child will be enabled and will
>   filter its data depending on it. Here how the filter options will look
>   like: 
>      
>      `field: "parentID",  //the dataValueField of the parent
>      operator: "eq",
>      value: "" //parent's value`

This means that the child dropdownlist (combobox) will use the field configured via `dataValueField` of the parent to do the filtering (cascading). In your case this doesn't work because `dataValueField` of the parent is set to "id". This field however serves a different purpose in the `productsList` array.

Currently there is no feature which allows one to specify the field used for cascading.

You have two options:

1. Do what @OnaBai suggested. Rename the "id" field of the `categoriesList` to "categorie_id" and set `dataValueField` accordingly.
2. Implement cascading manually. First remove the cascadeFrom option and then do this in the change event of the parent:

   ```
   change: function() {
       var products = $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList");

       products.dataSource.filter( {
         field: "categorie_id",
         value: this.value(),
         operator: "eq"
       });

       products.value(0);
   }
   ```

   Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ogEj/1/edit